# How can I write this in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

I'd like to write this in LaTeX, I just know how to write the equation but not the little text that are shown up and down.

[image]

Comment: Not about LaTeX, but note that the common definition of error is the other way round: measured value minus the "true" value. See e.g. https://jcgm.bipm.org/vim/en/2.16.html

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The formula is right but the annotations are in the wrong order.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano What if the exact value is greater than the measured value?

Comment: @Twink Uh? It doesn't matter, the error is a signed quantity.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Then the order doesn't matter, it can be defined in both ways.

Comment: @Twink Of course, but the convention in the field of measurement is the one I told you. But indeed you're free to choose your own convention, but depending on the purpose of what you're writing you can confuse some readers.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I've always seen it this order. http://math.stanford.edu/~zhangzy/math41/diff_error.pdf http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Differentials.aspx

Comment: In the linked documents, the term error is used in a slightly different sense.

Comment: It's the same as in the picture I posted, it's about differentials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hardest part is done below. The rest you can obtain by an analogy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
f(\underbrace{x+\overbrace{\Delta x}^{\substack{{\text{\makebox[0pt]{Measurement}}}\\ \text{error}}}}_{\substack{\text{Exact}\\ \text{value}}})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please oberve that some correction of spacing is needed, e.g., $f(\,...\,)$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to adjust this in case `\left(` and `\right)` were used to contain the argument of `f` (and not stretch so large as to contain the braces)?

Comment: @JānisLazovskis Probably beteer then `\left ... \right` will be `\bigl( ... \bigr)`.

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem of, for example, having `f(\frac{x}{2} + \Delta x)`, where `\bigl(` would be too small and `\left(` would be too large.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis You have series: `\bigl, \Bigl, \biggl, \Biggl` and (-r) and you can choose a version that you like.

Comment: But this $f(\underbrace{x}_{\substack{\text{Measured}\\ \text{Value}}})$ looks pretty ugly, not as in the picture. There's too much space between the braces.

Comment: @Twink It is left intentionally, to show the methods. If you add `\text{\makebox[0pt]{ ... }` around the word `error`, its length will be also neglected.